Matrix dimension assignment error encountered when solving matrix equation
I am trying to solve the equation T_SpSq=THS^-1·TPQ·THS.
I wrote a class to keep adding TPQ as a solution parameter.
But the compiler reports an error: C2338: YOU_MIXED_MATRICES_OF_DIFFERENT_SIZES.
I don't see where the data type is wrong. Please help me find the code and variables that may be wrong.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/MatrixFunctions> 

using namespace Eigen;

class Calibration {
public:
    Calibration(int max_iters = 100, double tol = 1e-6)
        : max_iterations(max_iters), tolerance(tol) {
        R_HS = Matrix3d::Identity();
        t_HS = Vector3d::Zero();
        T_HS = Matrix4d::Identity();
    }

    // Add a transformation matrix TPQ
    void addTPQ(const Matrix4d& TPQ) {
        TPQ_list.push_back(TPQ);
    }

    // Compute THS
    void computeTHS() {
        if (TPQ_list.size() < 2) {
            std::cerr << "At least two TPQ matrices are required to compute THS." << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        // Use least squares method to solve
        VectorXd params(6);
        params.head<3>() = Vector3d::Zero();  // Initial rotation parameters
        params.tail<3>() = t_HS;

        // Use LM optimization method
        for (int iter = 0; iter < max_iterations; ++iter) {
            VectorXd residuals = computeResiduals(params);
            MatrixXd J = computeJacobian(params);
            VectorXd delta = (J.transpose() * J).ldlt().solve(J.transpose() * residuals);
            params -= delta;
            if (delta.norm() < tolerance) {
                break;
            }
        }

        // Extract results
        Vector3d omega = params.head<3>();
        t_HS = params.tail<3>();
        R_HS = expMap(omega);

        // Update THS
        T_HS.topLeftCorner<3, 3>() = R_HS;
        T_HS.topRightCorner<3, 1>() = t_HS;

        // Output results
        std::cout << "Optimized R_HS:\n" << R_HS << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Optimized t_HS:\n" << t_HS.transpose() << std::endl;
    }

    // Return the computed THS
    Matrix4d getTHS() const {
        return T_HS;
    }

private:
    std::vector<Matrix4d> TPQ_list;
    Matrix3d R_HS;
    Vector3d t_HS;
    Matrix4d T_HS; // To store the computed THS
    const int max_iterations;
    const double tolerance;

    // Compute the exponential map from Lie algebra to rotation matrix
    Matrix3d expMap(const Vector3d& omega) {
        double theta = omega.norm();
        if (theta < 1e-6) {
            return Matrix3d::Identity();
        }
        Vector3d omega_hat = omega / theta;
        Matrix3d skew_omega_hat;
        skew_omega_hat << 0, -omega_hat.z(), omega_hat.y(),
            omega_hat.z(), 0, -omega_hat.x(),
            -omega_hat.y(), omega_hat.x(), 0;
        return Matrix3d::Identity() + sin(theta) * skew_omega_hat + (1 - cos(theta)) * (skew_omega_hat * skew_omega_hat);
    }

    // Compute the residual vector
    VectorXd computeResiduals(const VectorXd& params) {
        VectorXd residuals(12 * TPQ_list.size());
        Vector3d omega = params.head<3>();
        Vector3d t = params.tail<3>();
        Matrix3d R = expMap(omega);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < TPQ_list.size(); ++i) {
            Matrix3d R_A = TPQ_list[i].topLeftCorner<3, 3>();
            Vector3d t_A = TPQ_list[i].topRightCorner<3, 1>();

            Matrix3d R_res = R_A - R.transpose() * R_A * R;
            Vector3d t_res = t_A - R.transpose() * t_A - t + R.transpose() * t;

            residuals.segment<9>(12 * i) = Map<VectorXd>(R_res.data(), R_res.size());
            residuals.segment<3>(12 * i + 9) = t_res;
        }

        return residuals;
    }

    // Compute the Jacobian matrix
    MatrixXd computeJacobian(const VectorXd& params) {
        MatrixXd J(12 * TPQ_list.size(), 6);
        Vector3d omega = params.head<3>();
        Vector3d t = params.tail<3>();
        Matrix3d R = expMap(omega);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < TPQ_list.size(); ++i) {
            Matrix3d R_A = TPQ_list[i].topLeftCorner<3, 3>();
            Vector3d t_A = TPQ_list[i].topRightCorner<3, 1>();

            // Compute derivative for the rotation part
            Matrix3d dR_domega = Matrix3d::Zero(); // Initialize to zero matrix

            for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
                Vector3d omega_perturbed = omega;
                omega_perturbed[j] += 1e-8;
                dR_domega.col(j) = (expMap(omega_perturbed) - R) / 1e-8;
            }

            Matrix3d J_R = -R.transpose() * R_A * dR_domega;

            // Compute derivative for the translation part
            Matrix3d J_t = -Matrix3d::Identity();

            J.block<9, 3>(12 * i, 0) = Map<VectorXd>(J_R.data(), J_R.size());
            J.block<3, 3>(12 * i + 9, 3) = J_t;
        }

        return J;
    }
};

The error message says
> 1>D:\PCL\PCL 1.14.0\3rdParty\Eigen3\include\eigen3\Eigen\src\Core\AssignEvaluator.h(887,3): error C2338: YOU_MIXED_MATRICES_OF_DIFFERENT_SIZES
And there are the complete compiler message:
1>------ Build started: Project: Summary, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>main.cpp
1>D:\PCL\PCL 1.14.0\include\pcl-1.14\pcl\io\io.h(42,1): warning C4081: expected 'identifier'; found 'string'
1>D:\PCL\PCL 1.14.0\3rdParty\Eigen3\include\eigen3\Eigen\src\Core\arch\Default\Half.h(1,1): warning C4819: The file contains characters that cannot be represented in the current code page (936). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss.
1>D:\PCL\PCL 1.14.0\3rdParty\Eigen3\include\eigen3\Eigen\src\Core\arch\Default\BFloat16.h(1,1): warning C4819: The file contains characters that cannot be represented in the current code page (936). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss.
1>D:\PCL\PCL 1.14.0\3rdParty\Eigen3\include\eigen3\Eigen\src\Core\arch\Default\GenericPacketMathFunctions.h(676,1): warning C4819: The file contains characters that cannot be represented in the current code page (936). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss.
1>D:\PCL\PCL 1.14.0\include\pcl-1.14\pcl\visualization\interactor_style.h(1,1): warning C4819: The file contains characters that cannot be represented in the current code page (936). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss.
1>D:\PCL\PCL 1.14.0\include\pcl-1.14\pcl\visualization\pcl_visualizer.h(1603,1): warning C4819: The file contains characters that cannot be represented in the current code page (936). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss.
1>D:\PCL\PCL 1.14.0\3rdParty\VTK\include\vtk-9.3\vtkPolyDataMapper.h(1,1): warning C4819: The file contains characters that cannot be represented in the current code page (936). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss.
1>D:\PCL\PCL 1.14.0\include\pcl-1.14\pcl\keypoints\uniform_sampling.h(42,1): warning C4081: expected 'identifier'; found 'string'
1>D:\PCL\PCL 1.14.0\3rdParty\Eigen3\include\eigen3\Eigen\src\Core\AssignEvaluator.h(887,3): error C2338: YOU_MIXED_MATRICES_OF_DIFFERENT_SIZES
1>D:\PCL\PCL 1.14.0\3rdParty\Eigen3\include\eigen3\Eigen\src\Core\AssignEvaluator.h(858): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void Eigen::internal::call_assignment_no_alias<Dst,Src,Func>(Dst &,const Src &,const Func &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Dst=Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>,3,1,true>,
1>            Src=Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_quotient_op<double,double>,const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<double,double>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>>,const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>>>,
1>            Func=Eigen::internal::assign_op<double,double>
1>        ]
1>D:\PCL\PCL 1.14.0\3rdParty\Eigen3\include\eigen3\Eigen\src\Core\AssignEvaluator.h(836): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void Eigen::internal::call_assignment<Dst,Src,Eigen::internal::assign_op<double,double>>(Dst &,const Src &,const Func &,void *)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Dst=Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>,3,1,true>,
1>            Src=Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_quotient_op<double,double>,const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<double,double>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>>,const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>>>,
1>            Func=Eigen::internal::assign_op<double,double>
1>        ]
1>D:\PCL\PCL 1.14.0\3rdParty\Eigen3\include\eigen3\Eigen\src\Core\Assign.h(66): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void Eigen::internal::call_assignment<Derived,Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_quotient_op<double,LhsScalar>,const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<LhsScalar,double>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>>,const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>>>>(Dst &,const Src &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Derived=Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>,3,1,true>,
1>            LhsScalar=double,
1>            Dst=Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>,3,1,true>,
1>            Src=Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_quotient_op<double,double>,const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<double,double>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>>,const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>>>
1>        ]
1>D:\TextWorks\2024.05\Calibration\Summary\Summary\Calibration.h(124): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'Derived &Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::operator =<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_quotient_op<double,LhsScalar>,const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<LhsScalar,double>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>>,const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>>>>(const Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_quotient_op<LhsScalar,LhsScalar>,const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<LhsScalar,double>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>>,const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>>>> &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Derived=Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>,3,1,true>,
1>            LhsScalar=double
1>        ]
1>D:\TextWorks\2024.05\Calibration\Summary\Summary\Calibration.h(124): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'Derived &Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::operator =<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_quotient_op<double,LhsScalar>,const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<LhsScalar,double>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>>,const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>>>>(const Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_quotient_op<LhsScalar,LhsScalar>,const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<LhsScalar,double>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>>,const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>,const Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>>>> &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Derived=Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3,0,3,3>,3,1,true>,
1>            LhsScalar=double
1>        ]
1>Build project 'Summary.vcxproj' failed.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

The Calibration.h(124) is:

dR_domega.col(j) = (expMap(omega_perturbed) - R) / 1e-8;

in:
for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
                Vector3d omega_perturbed = omega;
                omega_perturbed[j] += 1e-8;
                dR_domega.col(j) = (expMap(omega_perturbed) - R) / 1e-8;
            }

in:

MatrixXd computeJacobian(const VectorXd& params) {


I tried to initialize some variables to 0 matrices or 0 vectors to allocate memory in advance, but the problem was not solved.

please include the complete compiler error message, in particular the line number would be interesting, you should indicate the line via a comment or similar. ANd please read about [mcve], it will be much simpler to spot the mistake if you remove anything from the code that is not directly needed to reproduce the error

Just from a causal look, the line dR_domega.col(j) = (expMap(omega_perturbed) - R) / 1e-8; assigns to a single column (left side). The right side includes R which is declared as a Matrix3d and expMap, which returns a Matrix3d. You cannot assign a matrix to a single matrix column

https://godbolt.org/z/e4jE1ahjf

You are trying assign some type of matrix of static size 3x3 to a block of static size 3x1.

Offtopic, why you are implementing your own function computeJacobian? I'm pretty sure Eigen already has something like that.
